# XUnit tests not executed anymore with Visual Studio 17.4.0

Tags: xunit, visual-studio-2022

Since upgrade to Visual Studio 2022 17.4.0, xunit tests are correctly displayed in test explorer, but they are not executed. They were correctly executed in previous versions. There is no error message.

We have "Tests in the group : 11". Results : 11 not executed.

Build is ok.

I'm using framework.net 4.8

Here is my project references

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.18.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.5">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.2.0">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Thanks.

Upgrading to VS Version 17.4.0.1 does not fix the problem.
upgrading to Framework 4.8.1 neither.
upgrading to latest version of xunit  neither.
Restarting, clearing and rebuild  neither.
Changing target processor to x64 or x86 or auto neither.

Comment: Is there any useful output in the VS output window? (Have to select "output from tests" after switching there.  I had a similar situation due to a crash in the test setup that brought the test process down before any tests had started.

Comment: I have this message : ========== Découverte de tests ignorée : tous les conteneurs de tests sont à jour ========== in english : test discovery ignored : all test containers are up to date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workaround is to downgrade Xunit package to xunit.runner.visualstudio 2.4.1 (last version is 2.4.5). I also downgraded Xunit to 2.4.1. Then I restarted the solution and the tests are running. Thanks Jérôme P. for the trick.